# Javascript redirect with headers or session id

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, basic-authentication

I have two web pages that I am trying to send information between. One is the login page that takes in the users information and calls a web-service to determine if the user is authenticated. Upon ensuring authentication I want to redirect to my other web page with some way of telling that the user has logged in and is authenticated.

I know that javascript has `window.location = url` but this does not forward the authentication header or anything else as far as I know. Is there a way to redirect with authentication headers or other way to tell the user is authenticated?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a standard method for doing that since javascript is a client side language but you have some alternative low-security solutions.Sessions are not necessary to function a client side language also for the better security you better stick to PHP or some other server side language.Because javascript can be easily skipped and it might put you in a trouble.

Just use your authenticated language for session and header functions also.

Hope this helped,
Regards.