# Redirect To A Url With Header Information Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript redirect with headers or session id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388066/javascript-redirect-with-headers-or-session-id)

How do I add header information in a redirect with javascript..

I redirect like this I think (not sure)..

```
  window.location.replace('https://anotherWebSite.com');
```

No I wanna add header information to it containing a userID="whatever" so when the redirect happens it will be available to anotherWebsite.com through this code for example..

```
   NameValueCollection headers = base.Request.Headers;
            for (int i = 0; i < headers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (headers.GetKey(i).Equals("userID"))
                {

                    _myID = headers.Get(i);
                }


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to attach response headers to a JavaScript redirect, but you could append the data to the querystring:

```
window.location.replace('https://anotherWebSite.com?user=[USERNAME]');
```

Comment: I cant use a querystring has to be in a header